# React .env.environment file's variable not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

I connected my react app with Contentful's database. When I give the access key directly, it works fine. But when I give an access key in `.env.environment` file, the variable does not work.

`contentful.js` file:

```
import {createClient} from 'contentful';

export default createClient({
  space: process.env.REACT_APP_API_SPACE,
  accessToken: process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
});
```

`.env.enviroment` file:

```
 REACT_APP_API_SPACE= my access key
 REACT_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN= my access token
```

Console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Expected parameter accessToken
at createClient (contentful.node.js:7563)
at Object.<anonymous> (Contentful.js:3)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap fafcbb2b670a4f50dfbb:555)
at fn (bootstrap fafcbb2b670a4f50dfbb:86)
at Object.<anonymous> (context.js:5)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap fafcbb2b670a4f50dfbb:555)
at fn (bootstrap fafcbb2b670a4f50dfbb:86)
at Object.<anonymous> (FeaturedRooms.js:2)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap fafcbb2b670a4f50dfbb:555)
at fn (bootstrap fafcbb2b670a4f50dfbb:86)
```

But it works fine when I give the access key directly in my contentful.js file like this:

```
import {createClient} from 'contentful';

export default createClient({
  space: my access key,
  accessToken: my access token
});
```

As I am uploading to Git, I don't want to give the key directly.

Comment: It should be named `.env` not `.env.environment`

Comment: Try restarting `npm run start` command.

Comment: You need to restart your React app every time you make some changes to environment file. Rerun npm.

Comment: is it a create-react-app project ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### #if using `create-react-app`

I don't think you can name your `.env` file like that, as of [create-react-app.dev](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used)

- `.env`: Default.
- `.env.local`: Local overrides. **This file is loaded for all environments** except test.
- `.env.development`, `.env.test`, `.env.production`: Environment-specific settings.
- `.env.development.local`, `.env.test.local`, `.env.production.local`: Local overrides of environment-specific settings.

So, your `.env.environment` env file by default shouldn't work. Unless you modified somehow.

#### Restarting your Server

If so, Dont forget to restart your server as [this note](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env),

> Note: You need to restart the development server after changing `.env` files.